# Avoid wrapping request object into InlineObject1 in OpenAPI Generator from OpenAPI 3.0 spec to Typescript

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate Typescript client with OpenAPI Generator 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT (our manager asked us to use that version for some reason) that reads an OpenAPI 3.0 spec. All of our current endpoints either accept data in query string or as form body, and they all work perfectly. I have a new endpoint that will read data as JSON in POST body (other endpoints will eventually be converted too). It will accept an object like the following:

`{email: "something@domain.com"}`

I'm trying to document the endpoint in YAML as following:

```
 /users/send-password-reminder:
    post:
      [...]
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                email:
                  type: string
      responses:
        [...]
```

However, when I generate the Typescript client, it generates a `SendPasswordReminderRequest` object, which wraps an autogenerated `InlineObject1` object, which wraps my actual `email`.

This causes me to use it like:

```
const req: SendPasswordReminderRequest = {
    inlineObject1:{
      email: "..."
  }
};

APIClient.user.sendPasswordReminder(req, ...)
```

What I want instead is to get rid of that `InlineObject1` completely and make `SendPasswordReminderRequest` directly wrap `email` property, and to be able to use it as:

```
const req: SendPasswordReminderRequest = {
   email: "..."
};

APIClient.user.sendPasswordReminder(req, ...)
```

I've tried defining the body in `components/requestBodies` and using `$ref`, and it still wraps the actual body even though it uses the name of my request body type.

How can I get rid of this wrapping?

Comment: What kind of TypeScript client are you generating?

Comment: I thought I had an answer for you but I misunderstood your question. You're trying to avoid the wrapping entirely whereas I though you were only trying to replace `inlineObject1` with `User`.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin exactly. if I create a schema explicitly with a name and reference it using `$ref`, `InlineObject1` is replaced by `MyNameThatIChoose`, but I want to remove wrapping altogether.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you're wanting to do is not built-in to any of the existing generators. One approach would be to create your own generator that forks an existing one.

Answer (score 12):

Im not sure if this will be still relevant for you but in code I find a way how to resolve not to generate InlineObjects at all

If you define "title" for your schema used in requestBody, it will use this `title` to name inline object.

So instead of getting InlineObject You can get something similar to: sendPasswordReminderRequestData, based on how you name your schema.

Hope this helps You or anyone else :).

Comment: Can you share example of this behaviour? Thanks ❤️

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to add the title to a POST request so it is generated with a friendly name via client generators (other data omitted for brevity):

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "paths": {
    "/Users/Hello": {
      "post": {
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "title": "UsersHelloRequest",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```